# Form de Collective a HTML Laravel (Form con Model)

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-9, laravelcollective

Buenas compañeros mi pregunta es la siguiente, como puedo colocar este formulario en html sin usar collective, les explico, estoy haciendo un tutorial y la persona del tutorial hace el siguiente código:

```
{!! Form::model($category, ['route' => 'categories.update', $category], 'method' => 'PUT) !!}
```

Este código es para actualiza una categoría, acá dejo como esta el controlador:

```
public function update(UpdatecategoryRequest $request, Category $category)
    {
        $category->update($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('categories.index');
    }
```

Y modelo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

      protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'description',
    ];

     public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

gracias de ante mano por cualquier sugerencia que puedan darme.

Yo intente lo siguiente:

```
<form action="{{ Route('categories.update') }}" method="PUT">
@csrf
```

me da el siguiente error:

```
Illuminate\Routing\ Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameter for [Route: categories.update] [URI: categories/{category}] [Missing parameter: category].
```

Se que me dice que falta un parametro, pero no se como colocarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="{{route('categories.update',$category->id)}}" method="POST">
 @csrf
 @method('PUT')
```

Por defecto los formularios no soportan otros métodos que no sean get y post, para ello debes agregar la directiva method y agregar el método que quieres utilizar https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#method-field

Comment: Muchísimas gracias

Comment: que buena respuesta sigue asi... incluiste el por que lo resuelve y la documentacion.